# How can I correctly quote Paths with spaces in them?

Tags: autohotkey

The below example does not execute as expected in Powershell:

```
Path := """C:\Temp\Test 1.svg"""
Run, C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7-preview\pwsh.exe -NoProfile -NoExit -Command Set-MetaData -Path %Path% -Notes "Hello" ,,
```

It will instead create a new file in `Temp` folder called `Test`
But if the Path being provided by the `Path` variable does not have any spaces in it, it runs as expected:

```
Path := """C:\Temp\Test1.svg"""
Run, C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7-preview\pwsh.exe -NoProfile -NoExit -Command Set-MetaData -Path %Path% -Notes "Hello" ,,
```

I've tried all sorts of things such as  expression syntax of `-Path "Path"" -Notes "Hello"`  I did not get positive results. Expression syntax always throws me of because of the double quotes , so am not sure if am doing it right.

Comment: in Powershell, I think you should use `$Path = """C:\Temp\Test 1.svg"""` to assign variable and call the variable with `$Path`, or are you writing batch command instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not escaping quotes enough.
You get into a real escape hell here and you actually seem to need quintuple quotes (`"""""test test"""""`) around the argument passed into pwsh.exe.
So in AHK you'd want

```
path := """""""""test test"""""""""
run, % "pwsh.exe -NoProfile -NoExit -Command echo " path
```

(Tested simply with the echo command because I don't have whatever `Set-MetaData` is)

To avoid this headache, you can use single quotes:

```
path := "'test test'"
run, % "pwsh.exe -NoProfile -NoExit -Command echo " path
```